# Get JSON data from driver console in selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, json, selenium, console.log

I need to get JSON data from console, which can be seen in 
 [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BhQK.png) image.

So far I have used the following codes:

```
j = driver.execute_script(" return document.getElementsByClassName('form-group text required assessment_questions_choices_text')")
```

I tried to save the data to a list, that didn't work as well.

```
list = []
list = driver.execute_script(" return document.getElementsByClassName('form-group text required assessment_questions_choices_text')")
```

Also, I came across a method online which can be found
[here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-the-browser-console-to-scrape-and-save-data-in-a-file-with-javascript-b40f4ded87ef/), using it I am able to get only the index of the data to an external file.

> {
>       "0": {},
>       "1": {},
>       "2": {},
>       "3": {},
>       "4": {} }

Looking for a way to import all data, with each attribute directly to my python code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The JS returns an HTMLCollection object, which python might have trouble fetching in a format you want. Try converting to an array before returning:
return Array.from(document.get...)
If that doesn't work, might have to fetch the data you want from the Collection individually.

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato This code returns just returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet that worked without any issue.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240545/get-json-data-from-driver-console-in-selenium-python"
driver.get(url)
elems = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('post-tag js-gps-track')")
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
driver.quit()
```

output:

```
javascript
python
json
selenium
console.log

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Edit 1:**

If you want to get the specific matching element then please use the below.

```
value = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('name_of_class')[0].innerHTML")
# or you can also use the below if you are interested in first item only
value = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.single_class')[0].innerHTML")
# query selector with multiple classes (class name with whitespaces)
value = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.class1.class2')[0].innerHTML")
```

Comment: Your code returns an empty list, however it did guide me in the proper direction.
`driver.execute_script("x = document.getElementsByClassName('name_of_class).item(0).innerHTML")

elems = driver.execute_script("return x")`

This seems to be working perfectly for me. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Glad that you are able to resolve the issue. Please check the updated answer with simple solutions. Make sure you accept the answer if you feel this answer resolved/helped you by clicking on accept button on the left hand side in my answer.

Comment: The answer above by @supputuri was the most help, however I was unable to get the required values by returning them directly as pointed out by him. A simple tweak by first saving everything to a variable and then returning it did the trick for me.